# Detect pinch-n-zoom on Macbook touchpad in Electron

Tags: macos, electron

The only way that I could find to detect pinch-n-zoom in Javascript is by means of [Gesture and Touch events](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkitjs/gestureevent). But those events are only implemented in Safari (not even chrome). The same code that detects gesture events in safari, didn't detect anything in my electron app. Is there any way to detect pinch-n-zoom or other two finger gestures on macbook trackpads in Electron?